# Unfortunately, your app has closed (caused by null reference, Bluetooth)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to create an application using android studio which should connect to my adruino board and send some numbers when pressing some buttons.

Right now I can't solve an error saying that my BluetoothAdapter variable is returning a NULL every time I use it. I tried the application on my phone and it would not run(Unfortunately, your app has closed).

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //variables-not using all of them but some are required in many examples for finding the MAC address
    Handler bluetoothIn;
    final int handlerState = 0;
    private BluetoothAdapter BA;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    //list for addresses
    private static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";
    public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //here I define my buttons

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

        final Button Up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
        Up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("1");
            }
        });
        final Button Down = (Button) findViewById(R.id.down);
        Down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("2");
            }
        });
        final Button Right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);
        Right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("3");
            }
        });
        final Button Left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);
        Left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("4");
            }
        });
        final Button Connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        Connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkBTState();
                doDiscovery();
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDevicesArrayAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        pairedListView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
        pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
        newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
        newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
        BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        checkBTState();
        if(BA.isEnabled()) {
            // Get a set of currently paired devices
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();

            // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    pairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
            } else {
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
                pairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }

    }

    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException { //something I have seen in one example I tried to copy

        return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
        //creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
        if (BA != null) {
            BA.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        /***************************************************/ // code here
        BluetoothDevice device = BA.getRemoteDevice(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                //insert code to deal with this
            }
        }
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        //I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check device is connected
        //If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and finish() will be called
     //   mConnectedThread.write("x");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            //Don't leave Bluetooth sockets open when leaving activity
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            //insert code to deal with this
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        //creation of the connect thread
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                //Create I/O streams for connection
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            // Keep looping to listen for received messages
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //write method
        public void write(String input) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);                //write bytes over BT connection via outstream
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //if you cannot write, close the application
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void doDiscovery() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doDiscovery()");

        // Indicate scanning in the title
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        // If we're already discovering, stop it
        if (BA.isDiscovering()) {
            BA.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
        BA.startDiscovery();
    }

    /**
     * The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
     */
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
            BA.cancelDiscovery();

            // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

            // Set result and finish this Activity
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
                // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                setTitle(R.string.select_device);
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void checkBTState() {
        // Check device has Bluetooth and that it is turned on
        BA=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(BA==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (BA.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
            } else {
                //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
com.example.mihaianca.helloword, PID: 13051
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mihaianca.helloword/com.example.mihaianca.helloword.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.mihaianca.helloword.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:113)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 

    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13051 SIG: 9
```

Thank you !

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking, as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Edit your question, add the logs there, as well as the Main. People usually wont bother searching the question bits all over. You have a NPE (Null Pointer Exception). Also, dont use Upper case for variable names.

Comment: The logcat is there. I am not sure what should I cut from the main code so it would make more sense. I posted it all here because I don't know where the problem starts.

Comment: Your problem lies in: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()' on a null object reference`, from the line `if(BA.isEnabled())` Check what ` BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();` states on the results it allows. Your BA variable is null. Finally, never name variables such as `Left` or `Connect ` first upper case letters are meant for classes.

Comment: Oh ok. Modified the button variables. Even if I remove the BA.isEnabled() it still gives me an error for next command used: getPairedDevices. I know it returns NULL, but how can I fix that?

Comment: It only returns NULL if the device does not support Bluetooth. So it should not be the case when running on my phone

Comment: Then some steps must be missing, edit your question, post your Manifest (at least the permissions used), also, give us details such as to what device you are running this on (Marshmallow? KitKat? Lollipop?). Can you confirm that the Bluetooth exists, is enabled, and has worked with some other Bluetooth device before?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get a bluetooth adapter like this:

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
```

I'm using it this way and it's working fine.

Comment: Is doing the same thing, but using the manager. Still Null as a return

Comment: Could you please explain me how you use the context? where and how should I declare it? Sorry for my previous answer, I realised I was not using a good API level.